# How to moveNext in DAO record set in MS Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Below is my code for DAO recordset.

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("getOrderRecords")
Set orderRST= qdf.OpenRecordset
Debug.Print "DAO Records"

txtRequestID = orderRST.Fields("OrderId")
```

Similar to txtRequestID , I have so many fields, which I plan to populate using DAO due to some design reasons.

The problem is, the first recordset object will come on FormLoad, but the second is not coming up if I moveNext in the navigate button. How can I code for the navigation. Someone pls help.

Comment: Please give us a little more information about what you are doing. How did you declare orderRST? Where does the Form/Form_Load event fit into this? Does populate mean you are writing the values into the Formfields? Why do you not assign the recordset to the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigateButton of the form is connected to the Recordsource of the form. If you create a separate variable with a recordset in it, it isn't connected to the form and thus the form navigation doesn't work.
Either set `Me.Recordsource="getOrderRecords"` or create a button and in the OnClick event set the move next: `orderRST.moveNext`.